# How to instantiate a class using an explicit first, and a default second argument, via the meta model?

Tags: metaprogramming, ceylon

I have the following toplevel class:

```java
class Example(shared String first = "default one", shared String second = "default two") {
}
```

Now, I want to instantiate this class using an explicit value for `first`, but the default value for `second`.

I know how to do this via explicitly compiled code, by using named arguments:

```java
void instantiateExample(String firstValue) {
    Example ex = Example { first = firstValue; };
    assert(ex.first == firstValue);
    assert(ex.second == "default two");
}
```

Now, I would like to do the same thing as the above code, but by using the `Class<Example, []|[String,String=]>` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with class model it is ...

```
Class<Example,[]|[String, String=]> exampleModel = `Example`;
value e1 = exampleModel();
value e2 = exampleModel("foo");
value e3 = exampleModel("foo", "bar");
```

or with class declaration it is ...

```
ClassDeclaration exampleDeclaration = `class Example`;
assert(is Example e1 = exampleDeclaration.instantiate());
assert(is Example e2 = exampleDeclaration.instantiate([], "foo"));
assert(is Example e3 = exampleDeclaration.instantiate([], "foo", "bar"));
```

HTH

Comment: Oh crap, I have inverted my first and second arguments when writing the question! My bad :( I will just wait to return home to check that my code works when the order is inverted. Also, great work on Ceylon. ;)

Comment: Hello, I have edited the question to switch the order of the two arguments - meaning that the call with ordered arguments does not work anymore. I would be glad if there was an answer to the modified question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I reedited the question to its original form as I found an answer for that on the ceylon-users list (by using namedApply from ceylon 1.1). Thank you.